# linking a specific field with another html page

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

This is the first page of my web app. when clicking one of the following sites, it goes to another page.

*Pic 1*
[image]

As shown in Pic 2, the details of the Persons that belong to the particular site should come automatically for each site. Is there a method to do this without creating different web pages for each site? If so, can anyone tell me the html and php code for the requirement. Thank you.

*Pic 2*
[image]

Comment: Include code in question

Comment: And your images are not web app

Comment: where is your code that you have tried?

Comment: You will use either `$_GET` or `$_POST`, but `$_GET` is enough

Comment: _"can anyone tell me the html and php code for the requirement"_ No. This isn't a free coding service. Do the research, make an attempt and come back if you run into some _specific_ issue. Your current question is _way_ to broad for SO.

Comment: onclick pass the unique id as query parameter to next page like this <a href="second_page.php?site_id=<?php echo $site_id ?>" >site A</a> there you can fetch the value from database with  select .... where site_id=$_GET['site_id']; and populate the table . now it is dynamic . you don't need to create new page of each site .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow my steps

1) Make the Location column as anchor tag with site unique id  like this

```
<a href="second_page.php?site_id=<?php echo $site_id1 ?>" >site A</a>
<a href="second_page.php?site_id=<?php echo $site_id2 ?>" >site B</a>
.
.
.
```

2) On click on anchor tag it will navigate you second page with site id .there you can fetch the value from database and populate the table.

```
select .... where site_id=$_GET['site_id'];
```

Now it is dynamic . you don't need to create new page of each site .

Comment: if my answer is useful mark it with green tick it's useful for future user reference @Lisa234

Answer (score 0):

[Pic 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiGJl.jpg)

```
[<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="project.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<form id="project" action="" method="POST">

    <h3><center>Project Details</center></h3>

    <fieldset> 
    <ul>

    <li><a href="../attendancesheet/index.php">Site A</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Site B</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Site C</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Site D</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Site E</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Site F</a></li>
    </ul>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>][2]
```

Comment: Unless this is an answer to your own question, you should update the _question_ with additional info. Don't post it as an answer.

Comment: i tried but i couldn't insert any more screenshots so i tried commenting.